# Common code for kernel and userspace

Tags: kernel, header-file

I'm working on a linux project. I want to have some code (to be specific, a struct) and a header file (my own implementation) common to both the kernel and the userspace. Can someone tell me how to implement this ?

Comment: You should ask programming questions such as this one on [so], not here. But why not just use one header in both parts of the project? I don't understand where you're running into a difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to just include the header in both (separately compiled) pieces of the project.  You can do that however you like; an obvious directory hierarchy might look like:

```
project/
    userspace_stuff/
    kernal_stuff/
    inc/
       project_namespace/
```

The `inc/project_namespace` is optional -- you could just as easily place the header in the toplevel and use `#include "../myheader.h"` in source files in the two subdirectories.  Personally, I find using relative paths with includes can get messy, so I like to have  an `inc` directory and absolute paths (`#include <project_namespace/myheader.h>`), facilitated by organizing a toplevel makefile with something like:

```
INC = -Iinc
CFLAGS += $(INC)
```